# android ASYNC task too slow

Tags: android, performance

So I have a button in Android.

When this button is pressed it runs an ASYNC task and then displays results of this task on the screen. However the code to display the results is running before the async task completes. is there a solution to this?

```
                size = 0;
                new initTask().doInBackground(); //get results
                setUpSeekBar();//display
                FillCards();//display
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code that you have called `doInBackground()` by your self . This is not a valid call when using `Asynctask`. You should call `execute()` and it will automatically call the Task (doInbackground()) . Here is what [execute(Params... params)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) does .

> Executes the task with the specified parameters. The task returns itself (this) so that the caller can keep a reference to it.

So you should change your code to.

```
new initTask().execute();
```

And use `AsyncTask's` methods to show the result on screen i.e [onPostExecute(Result result)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to display the results in the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask` (it is automatically called once the background task is completed). You can use an [in-line async task](https://gist.github.com/sheharyarn/5f66a854ce43e0c90521) for this:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // Background Code
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        setUpSeekBar();
        fillCards();
        // other stuff
    }
}.execute();
```